# What's the difference between "Have you slept" and "Are you asleep"?

Tags: meaning

If I ask someone:

> Have you slept?
>
> Are you asleep?

What's the difference in meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Have you slept?

Here *slept* is in the present perfect tense and is used to ask if the person slept before now at some indefinite point in time. It could mean "have you *ever* slept" but, more logically, it is asking if the person has slept recently (asked the next morning, for example).

> Are you asleep?

Here *asleep* is in the present tense. The question is directed at a person who may or may not currently be sleeping in an attempt to discover which is the case.

Comment: I agree, except that _have you slept_ is present perfect, not past. Past would be _did you sleep?_ The difference doesn't affect the point you are making.

Comment: @col Thanks for the correction :)

Comment: Logically, the only answer possible to 'Are you asleep?' must be 'No'.

Comment: @mich Or a non-response (affirming yes).

Comment: Is silence an answer?